# Как сделать так чтобы контент залазил под border-image?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть типичный блок, на который по заданию нужно накинуть `border-image`.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы контент залазил под бордер?

Без этого имею большие отступы и совсем некрасиво.

[Ссылка на мой project1](https://konstantin-voronenko-project1.gunniq.repl.co/border-image.html)

```css
.border {
  border: 100px solid transparent;
  -webkit-border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXyAI.png') 100 100 stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="border" style="overflow: auto; min-width: 100px;">
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">ФУТБОЛ</h2>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gjml.jpg" width="200" style="margin: 0 20px 20px 0">
  <p>Футбо́л (англ. football от foot «ступня» + ball «мяч») — командный вид спорта, в котором целью является забить мяч в ворота соперника ногами или другими частями тела (кроме рук) большее количество раз, чем команда соперника. В настоящее время самый
    популярный и массовый вид спорта в мире</p>
  <p>Есть 17 официальных правил игры, каждое из которых содержит список оговорок и руководящих принципов. Эти правила предназначены для применения на всех уровнях футбола, хотя есть некоторые изменения для таких групп, как юниоры, взрослые, женщины и люди
    с ограниченными физическими возможностями. Законы очень часто формулировались в общих чертах, которые позволяют упростить их применения в зависимости от характера игры. Правила игры публикуются в ФИФА, но поддерживаются Международным советом футбольных
    ассоциаций</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам поможет

```
background-clip: border-box
```